# Unit test mockito repository return null

Tags: java, spring, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I'm testing dynamodb repository. Here is the method to test

```
public Book getBook(final String bookId) {
    DynamoDbTable<Book> bookTable = getTable();
    Key key = Key.builder().partitionValue(bookId)
        .build();
    return bookTable.getItem(key);
  }

  private DynamoDbTable<Book> getTable() {
    return dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("Book",
        TableSchema.fromBean(Book.class));
  }
```

Here is the test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class BookRepositoryTest {

  @Mock
  private DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient;
  @Mock
  private DynamoDbTable<Book> dyamoDbTable;
  @Mock
  private Key key;

  @InjectMocks
  private BookRepository repository;

  private final String BOOK_ID = "123";
  private static MockedStatic<TableSchema> tableSchema;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void init() {
    tableSchema = mockStatic(TableSchema.class);
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void close() {
    tableSchema.close();
  }

  @Test
  void testGetBook() {
    Book book = HelperMethod.createBook();
    tableSchema.when(() -> TableSchema.fromBean(Book.class))
        .thenReturn(BeanTableSchema.create(Book.class));
    when(dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("Book",
        TableSchema.fromBean(Book.class))).thenReturn(dyamoDbTable);
    when(dyamoDbTable.getItem(key)).thenReturn(book);
    final var result = repository.getBook(BOOK_ID);
    assertEquals(book, result);
  }

}
```

Here is the error

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
Expected :Book(bookId=123, keyCode=testKeyCode, eventTimestampMs=123, value=true)
Actual   :null

Answer (score 0):

You never mocked `dyamoDbTable` (which appears to be misspelled), so it is `null`. Also, I don't see why you need to mock `TableSchema.fromBean`; it seems like you could just do

```
when(dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(dyamoDbTable)
```

If you did that, you wouldn't need `mockStatic`.

Comment: now i have this still the same error
`void testGetBook() {
    Book Book = HelperMethod.createBook();
    DynamoDbTable dynamoDbTable = mock(DynamoDbTable.class);
    when(dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(dynamoDbTable);
    when(dynamoDbTable.getItem(key)).thenReturn(book);
    assertEquals(book, repository.getDoorState(BOOK_ID));
  }`